# Ordering on multiple fields

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Imagine as simple case where your are either the `designer`, `developer` or `reviewer` stored in a table `work` like so:

```
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
| id | designer | developer | reviewer |    
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
| 1  | sudo_O   | fred      | bob      |
| 2  | fred     | bob       | sudo_O   |
| 3  | bob      | sudo_O    | fred     |
| 4  | sudo_O   | fred      | bob      |
| 5  | bob      | sudo_O    | fred     |
| 6  | fred     | bob       | sudo_O   |  
| 7  | fred     | bob       | john     |   
| 8  | john     | bob       | fred     | 
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
```

To query the table to find all the my work would be:

```
select * from work where designer='sudo_O' or developer='sudo_O' or reveiwer ...
```

Is it possible to order the results by type of work *i.e* design, development, review like so:

```
1, sudo_O, fred, bob
4, sudo_O, fred, bob
3, bob, sudo_O, fred
5, bob, sudo_O, fred
2, fred, bob, sudo_O
6, fred, bob, sudo_O
```

That is all the design work for me is shown first, followed by development, then by review.

Comment: is it your output display you posted??

Comment: What do you mean by *type of work*? you mean specific type (i.e. `sudo_0` then `bob` then `fred`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id, designer, developer, reviewer
FROM work 
WHERE designer = 'sudo_O' OR developer = 'sudo_O' OR reviewer = 'sudo_O'
ORDER BY 
    CASE 'sudo_O' 
        WHEN designer  THEN 1
        WHEN developer THEN 2
        WHEN reviewer  THEN 3
    END, id ;
```

or like this (might be more efficient on a big table and with 3 indexes, one on each column):

```
SELECT id, designer, developer, reviewer
FROM 
  ( SELECT id, designer, developer, reviewer, 1 AS ord
    FROM work 
    WHERE designer = 'sudo_O' 
  UNION ALL
    SELECT id, designer, developer, reviewer, 2
    FROM work 
    WHERE developer = 'sudo_O' 
  UNION ALL
    SELECT id, designer, developer, reviewer, 3
    FROM work 
    WHERE reviewer = 'sudo_O'
  ) AS t
ORDER BY ord, id ;
```